# I used the msa package in R to visualize multiple sequence comparisons, but an error occurred

Tags: r

I'm trying to use the msa package in R for visualization of multiple sequence comparison analysis and I'm getting errors

`Error in texi2dvi(texfile, quiet = !verbose, pdf = identical(output, "pdf"), :  pdflatex is not available`

I don't know why this is

code:

```
library(msa)
mySequences <- readAAStringSet('./result.fasta')
myFirstAlignment <- msaMuscle(mySequences, order = 'input')


msaPrettyPrint(myFirstAlignment,
                output = 'pdf',
                file = 'SPL.pdf',
               showNames="left", showNumbering="none", showLogo="top",
               showConsensus="bottom", logoColors="rasmol",
               verbose=FALSE, askForOverwrite=FALSE)
```

I did a Google search but found no answer

Comment: you seem to miss the pdflatex program required for drawing the alignment. On linux it is often packaged with the name of  _texlive_

Comment: I am drawing on Windows